# ActiveAdmin for user dashboard or only admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I came across ActiveAdmin a couple of days ago and did several test on existing projects.
ActiveAdmin is really great and I was wondering if it could make any sense to use it as:
- a user dashboard (widget approach)
- an admin tool
For instance, I could use only one model (User) and add a role attribute (nil or 'admin') and authorize administrative tasks for admin role only.
Would this be a good approach ?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be a good approach, you'd just restrict different content to the role of the user. This way all of your users get the same dashboard, just different content shown to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luc -- I have heard a lot of good things about ActiveAdmin, but I have had several experiences with going with "all in one" solutions like this.  There's a *lot* of code going on here (even just the bundled Devise authentication is a handful for many), so you are making a big commitment to the way this code is written, how well it's maintained, and how flexible it is.

We used something similar to get a nice back-end UI for an app, and we were rolling fast for the first few months.  As our needs got more sophisticated, we started realizing that we were sort of boxed in.  It wasn't maintained regularly and hindered our ability to get up to new versions of ruby and Rails.  We ended up forking the code and over the course of several years finding that we were regularly doing battle with it.  It's possible (perhaps even likely) that this gem is really well designed and capable ... but it's more like an application framework than just a little gem.  To be sure this isn't always the case.

Read the code and make sure you understand it well enough to know it's right for you.

Comment: Quite agree with you, that is more than a little gem. Thanks for your feedback, that is really helpful. In fact I already use Devise and a couple of other gem and the compatibility isue is surely to consider.